# Get redbean instance

Tags: php, orm, redbean

I need to get the redbean instacne and pass it to the model functions that I need to. [This document](http://redbeanphp.com/downloads/redbean.pdf) says a way of doing it.

```
$toolbox = RedBean_Setup::kickstart('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo','root','');
$redbean = $toolbox->getRedBean();
```

But it dose not work. It gives me error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getRedBean() on a non-object in ...
```

I can see the method is there. How could I achive this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution after little digging of source. It can be get in following way. It seams this should be added to the RedBean document.

```
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=t2odemo','root','');
$toolbox = R::$toolbox;
$redbean = $toolbox->getRedBean();
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still out there trying to get the `redBean` instance,
this works for me (version 4.3.2):

```
R::setup(...credentials stuff);
$redBean = R::getToolBox();
$rbInstance = $redBean->getDatabaseAdapter();
```